Admin page in wordpress is not working after installing wordpress in cpanel
I need help with cpanel (crazydomain's hosting), I'm starting a new website, bought domain and business hosting on crazydomain. My problem is after installing wordpress, I tried going to the admin link, it says 'This page isn’t working'.
I tried going to the mysql databases and checked for error, there's no error.
Tried cleaning DNS, didn't work.

Have you tried by removing server cache?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
